# Trying to parse Excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to parse excel file in such a way that when I find an empty cell I add to the value of string. Sample code:

```
for (int e = 0; e < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); e++) {
    sheet = wb.getSheetAt(e);
    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if(row != null) {
            cell = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                cell = row.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue("foo");
            }
            cell = row.getCell(1, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue("bar");
            }
            cell = row.getCell(2, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue(0.0);
            }
        }
}
```

I tried many solutions, and I always get an exception NullPointerException.

Comment: It would be useful to know in which line the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: at line if(cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {

Comment: If cell is null, it may  fail at this line `if(cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)`

Comment: What exactly did you try? RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL sounds mightily suspicious, doesn't it. Almost like it implies that it could return NULL in some cases. Maybe you should check for that for cell 0.

Answer (score 1):

Could be useful to know which line gives you the exception, but I bet it's this one:

```
cell = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
if(cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
```

As far as I know, the policy RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL [returns a null value](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL) if the cell is empty. So, if you get a blank cell there, the `cell.getCellType()` in the if statement raises a NullPointerException.

Comment: So what I need to do to know that the cell is empty, without getting an exception?

Comment: You could go as in the other columns, where you correctly checked if(cell == null).

Answer (score 0):

You have NPE in first check, the cell is null:

```
cell = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
if(cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
```

later you check correctly:

```
cell = row.getCell(2, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
if(cell == null) {
```

to create new cell use

```
Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK
```

Comment: This is because I wanted to see all the possibilities, and neither one did not work properly

Comment: @user1853125 - as someone mentioned RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL will return NULL if the cell is empty. Then you get NPE in first code snippet.

Comment: ok when i change it to Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK I also get the NPE

Comment: @user1853125 - try Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK

Comment: I'll try this solution, but the first results are not working